# How to grep text from a specific line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I need to grep text from a specific line.

I don't need to grep from the whole file, but only one line.

`CATS_COLOR_TEST=$(grep FF0000 "${STYLE_FILENAME}")`

how to specify a line, for example, I need 31.

Comment: `awk 'NR == 31' ${STYLE_FILENAME} | grep FF0000 `

Comment: Hi Mishel, this questions seems less programming oriented and more tool usage and so out of scope. You might get better results over at https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use single `awk` like this:

```
CATS_COLOR_TEST=$(awk 'NR == 31 && /FF0000/' "$STYLE_FILENAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use head and tail like so:

```
head -n 31 file_to_grep | tail -n 1
```